# SQLite and UTF8

Tags: qt, sqlite, function

I have a strange problem. Cant add function to sqlite/ Write on c++/Qt. 
Function should do upper to Utf-8 simbols;

```
    this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    this->db.setDatabaseName(db);
    this->db.open();
    QVariant v = this->db.driver()->handle();
    sqlite3 *handler = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(v.data());
    sqlite3_create_function( handler, "myUpper", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, myFunc, NULL, NULL )
```

and the function is:

```
void myFunc( sqlite3_context * ctx, int argc, sqlite3_value ** argv )
{
        if( argc != 1 ) return;
        QString str;
        switch(sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]))
        {
                case SQLITE_NULL:
                {
                        sqlite3_result_text( ctx, "NULL", 4, SQLITE_STATIC );
                        break;
                }
                case SQLITE_TEXT:
                {
                        QString wstr((char*)sqlite3_value_text16(argv[0]));
                        wstr = wstr.toUpper();
                        sqlite3_result_text16( ctx, wstr.toStdString().c_str(), wstr.size() , SQLITE_TRANSIENT );
                        break;
                }
                default:
                        sqlite3_result_text( ctx, "NULL", 4, SQLITE_STATIC );
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the problem, but I suppose you should pass a pointer to the function:

```
sqlite3_create_function(handler, "myUpper", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, &myFunc, NULL, NULL)
```

EDIT:
I you're passing to the function wstr.toStdString().c_str(). This is not allowed because the pointer returned is only temporary and will go out of scope. What I would do is:

```
...
case SQLITE_TEXT: {
   QString wstr((char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]));
   wstr = wstr.toUpper();
   QByteArray array = wstr.toLocal8Bit();
   const char* cstr = array.data();
   sqlite3_result_text(ctx, cstr, wstr.size() , SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   break;
}
...
```

I didn't try it so check this.

Comment: This isn't solved problem. Program suddenly shutdown, then i'm trying to open base and init function.

Comment: this is'n solved problem. Problem's exectly the same as it was.

Comment: Problem is... you didn't say what the problem you're experiencing is... Have you tried to put some debugging logs or running in debug?

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS THAT THE PROGRAM CRASHES WHEN I OPEN DB

Comment: The problem become more interesting. This bug catches on x64 system. On x86 there isn't this problem. Can you explain this? And help in this aspect.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this I posted some time ago may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289623/using-sqlite-custom-functions-with-qt. Never solved that problem.