# QtSql Fuzzy search

Tags: qt, sqlite, fuzzy-search, qsqldatabase

I am working with QSQLITE database in qt and attempt to implement fuzzy search in our program our sql query is something like this:

```
select name from things where name like '%arg%'
```

it's not the same the query is longer has joins and etc.
I tried using SOUND and SOUNDEX() but I think none of them is supported in QSQLITE is there any way I can implement fuzzy search here?

Answer (score 0):

For [soundex support](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#soundex), you would have to recompile the SQLite library embedded in Qt.

There is no other built-in 'fuzzy' function.
Either implement your own [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289623/using-sqlite-custom-functions-with-qt), or store a normalized version of your string in the database so that you can compare it directly.

Comment: I tried recompiling the SQLite with soundex but how can i embed it in qt?

Comment: You have to recompile Qt.