# Flutter project, database query with REGEXP causes DatabaseException on iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, sqlite

My flutter app uses an SQLite database, using the sqlfite plugin:

```
sqflite: ^2.0.2
```

One of my queries uses the REGEXP function. I'm developing and testing on Android and have had no issues. However when testing the app on iPhone, I get the following fatal error:

```
DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "no such function: REGEXP" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no such function: REGEXP})
```

Is there anything I can do that will enable the REGEXP function to be usable on iPhone, or must I find a different way of coding my query?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears that REGEXP is not officially recognised by sqlite until very recently, so you cannot guarantee that different platforms will be able to use the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Likely sqlite binary was built without support for RegExp. This usually comes as external command compiled as external function and registered at runtime.

Check for the problem:
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/922

Check for solution:
[SQLite in C and supporting REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288287/sqlite-in-c-and-supporting-regexp)